# How to add dynamic google map to my website for locations

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a business directory website and i need to show the user business location on google map for each users.

When the user entered that particulat place in to the textbox and then click on the update map button,

How to show the entered place in google map on my website. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You will have to use the geocoding service.

> Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), which you can use to place markers or position the map.

You can [check this for more](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)